# Search all rows with the same tag in many to many polymorphic

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and have a many to many polymorphic relationship like this to my tagging system.

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string
    url - string


tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

Now, I'm creating a search page to search all posts and videos with the same tag? I thought about union in MySQL but videos and posts table columns' are not equal.
Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Eloquent style to achieve this. Assume I find all posts and videos with tag id = 1;

```
$tag = Tag::with(['posts', 'videos'])->find(1);
    $relations = $tag->getRelations();


$posts = $relations['posts']; // Collection of Post models
$videos = $relations['videos']; // Collection of Video models

$allRelations = array_merge($posts->toArray(), $videos->toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use power of Eloquent.

Create model files (`Post.php`, `Video.php`, `Tag.php`).

Post.php

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}
```

Video.php

```
class Video extends Eloquent {

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}
```

Tag.php

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Video');
    }

}
```

More on this you can read in Laravel [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) documentation.

Next, instead of `taggeables` create two pivot tables: first `post_tag` with fields `tag_id` and `post_id` to connect posts with tags, and second `tag_video` with fields `video_id` and `tag_id` to connect videos  with tags.

And finally, to get all posts and videos with the same tag id (let's say $tag_id) you can do something like this (if your `Post.php` model really contains `tags()` method):

For posts:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas(`tags`, function($q) {
    $q->where('id', '=', $this->id);
})->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

For videos:

```
$videos = Video::whereHas(`tags`, function($q) {
    $q->where('id', '=', $this->id);
})->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks you for you answer but in my questions, I said that I set up a many to many polymorphic relationship and I don't want to change that structure. I answered this question my self.